# What is the best way to convey duplicate content or task already exists message?

Tags: usability, interface, error-message, warnings, app

App context is a simple todo task app.

So, what would be the best way to convey to the user the task already exists on the list?

Basically, I want to keep the message and prompt as humorous and less annoying respectively.

Comment: An humorous way could be to talk about "[senility](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/senility)" but not sure that it is a good thing for your app.

Comment: @YohannV. yeah that would look lil insulting

Comment: You can make your appli *talk* : "Oh ! I was pretty sure I had already typed this..."

Comment: @YohannV. yeah I am also thinking of something like that but then was thinking is it suitable to show long sentence if the case is about mobile app

Comment: Why a to do task list needs to provide this information? I am assuming that duplicating a task causes no harm in a to do list... as I understood your question.

Comment: @SSuad I am thinking why to list the same twice multiple times and what if user sets a reminder for one task and forgets and then again sets a different time for the same task or something like that

Comment: I don't think this sentence is that long. But if you want a short one, you can try a *"Oh ! Again ?!"*

Comment: @YohannV. hahaha that made me laugh .. yeah this one is great

Comment: Glad you liked it. ^^ We will need a screenshot or something visual to go further in design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way has fulfill two needs:

1. Explain the user error
2. Stop the error from occurring

This is best done with an alert, typically. The language you use is up to you. I'd suggest something like "D'oh! You already have [taskname]"

But be aware of the usability challenges associated with it. Does the alert offer a way to retain the data, meaning return to edit? If not, what is the action?

In my experience the language is important but the functionality wins the day. Or, the way I think of it, users come for the functionality but stay for the form.

Comment: yeah fully agreed on `functionality wins the day`